# How do I reiterate over the last iteration?

Tags: python, json, loops

I have an unordered dict/json object of data. In fact I have many of those, line by line in a file. There are three keys/objects in each one. I never know which of the three has the data I need to add right back onto the other two. I cannot control how the data is initially written, whether I like it or not.

Currently I iterate over each of the three keys/objects until I find the correct key that has the fields I need. I then save them off to variables. Now, how do I go right back over the other two keys/objects that I might of already iterated over and add the fields and values back into them? As I said there are multiples of these from a file so it will just keep going on to the next one if I don't... reiterate?

Code:

```
    with open(inputfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            # File is one big json object per line. Load up the current line as JSON.
            line = json.loads(line)
            for result in line['scan_result']:
                # Check if this object's filename field has the extra data I need to parse out and palce in t he others.
                if "meta_data" in file_result['filename']:
                    print "FOUND METADATA"
                    #print result['filename']
                    regmatch = re.match(".*meta_data_(.+?)_(.+?):(.+?)$", file_result['filename'])
                    if regmatch:
                        print "REG MATCH -------------"
                        #print regmatch.groups()
                        timecreated = regmatch.group(1)
                        author = regmatch.group(2)
                        mime_type = regmatch.group(3)
```

So as you can see, I have the data pulled out. I just need to figure out how to put it  back into the JSON objects I just iterated over. I'm open to doing this other ways to. Maybe sorting the object first and then running through it?

If it helps, the data structure looks like this. The order of the parent is never known though. This is one "line" (json object) in the file:

```
{
    "filename": abc.gif
    id : 13241
    parent : 999
    interesting_file_stuff : {
        stuff : 123
        stuff2 : 456
    }
}
{
    "filename": hello.zip+meta_data_stuff_here
    id : 999
    parent : NA
    interesting_file_stuff : {
        stuff : 5435
        stuff2 : 24223
    }
}
{
    "filename": xyz.exe
    id : 8342
    parent : 999
    interesting_file_stuff : {
        stuff : 2
        stuff2 : 3232
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra boolean while loop.
You could have an extra loop which is while True, repeat until you use a break statement, then the outer loop will increment to the next value.

```
for line in f:
    while True:
        # do stuff
        if condition:
            break
        # do more stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for loops can't go backwards, so I'll have to manually loop through with a while loop, giving complete control of the iterations and which way I go.